# PDO - Problema com FetchAll

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Boa tarde amigos, meu problema hoje é o seguinte. Tenho a seguinte query:

```
set @row_number = 0;
SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number,il.* from itemloja il order by il.LojaId
```

Como podem ver, são duas que se dependem.
Eu quero pegar o resultado dela no PHP, então uso

```
$results = $go->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Porém ele está dando o seguinte erro:

> General error' PDOStatement->fetchAll(2)

Já tentei O `FETCH_ORI_FIRST` com o `FETCH_ORI_NEXT` e também não adiantou.
Alguem sabe como posso resolver isso?

### EDIT

Esse é o meu codigo

```
    $Query = "set @row_number = 0; 
              SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number,il.* 
              from itemloja il order by il.LojaId";

    $go = $pdo->prepare($Query);
    $go->execute();
    $results = $go->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Poste mais código que envolve a chamada ao $go->fetchAll. Mostre pra gente onde você define o valor da variável $go para que possamos analisar melhor seu problema.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu feito, o erro se dá ali na ultima linha mesmo

Answer (score 2):

Você está executando múltiplas queries com PDO, o que normalmente não é suportado.

A primeira query é composta por `set @row_number = 0;` (note o `;` ao final do *statement*) e a segunda query é

```
SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number,il.* 
from itemloja il order by il.LojaId";
```

Suas opções são a) utilizar o PHP para contar linha por linha ou b) abilitar queries múltiplas no PDO.

### Adicionar um contador através do PHP

```
// Query simples, sem vários statements
$Query = "SELECT il.* FROM itemloja il ORDER BY il.LojaId";

$go = $pdo->prepare($Query);
$go->execute();
$results = $go->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$i = 0;
foreach($results as $it){
    $it->rowNumber = ++$i;
}
```

---

### Trabalhar com múltiplas Queries com PDO_MYSQLND

> *Conteúdo originalmente postado por [Sam Dark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209566/sam-dark)(modificado por [Your Common Sense](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense)) no [StackOverflow English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd/6461110#6461110) e traduzido por [mim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1014588/marco-aur%C3%A9lio-deleu)*

Para executar múltiplas queries você precisará

- PHP 5.3+
- MySQLND
- Emulador de *Prepared Statement*. Tenha certeza de que `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` está configurado como `1` (padrão). Outra opção é usar `$pdo->exec` diretamente.

**exec**

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", 'root', '');

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 0);

$sql = "set @row_number = 0; 
        SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number,il.* 
        from itemloja il order by il.LojaId";

try {
    $db->exec($sql);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

**statements**

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", 'root', '');

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 1);

$sql = "set @row_number = 0; 
        SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number,il.* 
        from itemloja il order by il.LojaId";
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas ainda continua dando o mesmo erro anterior

Comment: @LuanGabriel vc tentou a primeira opção só pra ver se o erro desaparece?

Comment: Tentei sim amigo, com a primeira opção ele roda ok.

Comment: @LuanGabriel isso significa que o problema realmente é causado pela query múltipla.

Answer (score -1):

dá um print do phpinfo() na parte onde está o PDO e pdo_mysqlnd ou qualquer outro que você esteja usando para "ligar" o pdo ao mysql;

se tiver certeza que ele tá com multiquery, acrescenta a linha:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 0);
```

antes da QUERY.

LEMBRANDO, essa função multiqueries habilitada torna os ataques de SQL Injection mais sucentíveis....